# Best Rail pass for Switzerland

Tags: trains, tickets, switzerland, zurich

I am looking to check out the best rail pass which would fit my itinerary, I checked on https://www.swiss-pass.ch/ but it says passes are available minimum for 3 days.
My itinerary looks like below:

**Monday** : Fly from AMS to Zurich. Reach Zurich by 8 am and then go to Lucerne. From Lucerne go to Interlaken. Explore area of Interlaken and Lauterbrunnen (if time permits). Return to Lucerne in the evening.

**Tuesday** : Explore Lucerne in the morning and in the afternoon leave for Zurich. Visit Zurich Museums and other tourist places. Leave for Amsterdam in the evening.

Total days I will be spending in Switzerland is **2 days** .

What would be my best pass option via which I can access all trains/trams in Switzerland. Apologies if this might seem a trivial query, I am visiting Switzerland for the first time.

Comment: Have you checked how much it'd be just buying the tickets separately? When are you travelling? Sometimes there are special day passes available (e.g. right now from Coop/Interdiscount) and there are discount day passes that you can buy in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I'll try to make this answer a bit more general than for your specific itinerary.

### Quick conclusions

- Many trips on mountain railways/cable cars: Swiss Travel Pass
- Simpler planning and more flexibility: Swiss Travel Pass
- European-domiciled travellers: probably Interrail
- Young travellers (before 25th birthday): probably Swiss Travel Pass
- Frequent travellers: annual half-fare travel card
- Lucky option (if timing is right, if local friends are available): special day pass or municipal day pass
- Standard option: discount day pass

### If you will travel a lot on certain touristic mountain railways/cable cars

Certain touristic mountain railways/cable cars such those in Jungfrau region or near Zermatt do not offer discount to the other passes mentioned below, but do have 50% discount for half-fare card holders and Swiss Travel Pass holders.

If you will take these touristic railways/cable cards (e.g. Jungfraujoch or Zermatt-Gornergrat), lack of discount on these very expensive tickets can quickly eat away the otherwise cheaper price of the other passes that are more advantageous for normal train routes.

For example, the savings on Zermatt-Gornergrat alone are worth 63.- (return trip, June-August price). Interrail and other day passes do not give right to discount on this route.

[MySwissAlps](https://www.myswissalps.com/) is a very helpful website when planning trips in Switzerland and it often has detailed information on the discount available to different kind of travel passes.

### If you live in Europe and take mostly trains

For European residents, [Interrail One Country Pass for Switzerland](https://www.interrail.eu/en/interrail-passes/one-country-pass/switzerland) is a very competitive offer. For example, for three days in one month, it is 49 EUR per day for adults, 42 EUR per day for youths.

Even if you only use two days, it may still be cheaper than other offers.

The youth definition for Interrail is also more extensive, the youth price applies before your 28th birthday (instead of 25th like most Swiss offers).

As it is a rail pass, its covered area is different from the coverage area of Swiss Travel Pass or other Swiss-issued travel passes.

[Most train companies](https://www.interrail.eu/en/plan-your-trip/tips-and-tricks/trains-europe/railway-companies/swiss-railway-companies-included) (including the main one, Swiss Federal Railways) are included in the pass and some ferries are also discounted.

Urban trains (S-Bahn) are included, but buses and trams are not.

It also gives a discount (often 25%) on [certain mountain railways.](https://www.interrail.eu/en/plan-your-trip/tips-and-tricks/trains-europe/railway-companies/swiss-railway-companies-discounted)

Minor differences in coverage area of the other passes exist! For example, the train to Rigi Kulm is included in Swiss-issued passes but only discounted 50% on Interrail.

### If you are under 25

[Swiss Travel Pass](https://www.sbb.ch/fr/loisirs-et-vacances/inspiration/voyageurs-internationaux/swiss-travel-pass.html) for youth can be a great deal starting at 21 per day (15 days) up to 55.- per day (3 days consecutive) or 63.- per day (3 days flexible). European domicile is not requried.

### If you come to Switzerland a lot

You may want to consider getting a [half-fare subscription](https://www.sbb.ch/en/travelcards-and-tickets/railpasses/half-fare-travelcard.html) (185.- first year, 165.- afterwards; before 25th birthday: 120.- first year, 100.- afterwards). It gives you 50% discount (or sometimes less on special, regional or low-value fares) on all regular public transport and most mountain railways and cable cars in Switzerland.

You also benefit from a [regular day pass](https://www.sbb.ch/en/travelcards-and-tickets/tickets-for-switzerland/day-pass/day-pass-for-the-half-fare-travelcard.html) at 75.- and further discount on "supersaver" train tickets and day passes.

The regular half-fare subscription does not have a residency requirement. Special offers sometime are only applicable to customers residing in Switzerland and neighbouring countries.

### If you will only take a couple train rides in total

Booking specific trains in advance may be cheaper. The [SBB website](https://www.sbb.ch/en/timetable.html) and app are well-made and all Swiss public transport options (train, bus, tram, boat, some mountain railways and cable cards) are integrated. There are often "supersaver" tickets available at a much cheaper price than the normal tariff. Of course, the number of saver tickets is limited and usually the discount becomes smaller as travel dates near. Peak periods (holidays, weekends, etc.) also often have less discount or sell out quickly.

Unlike most normal train tickets (and day passes/Swiss Travel Pass), the tickets are only valid on the specific train at the specific date and time indicated on the tickets.

If you do not make the specific trains on time because your flight got delayed or reasons not of the railways' fault, the tickets are refundable less a fee (10.-) if you purchase a standard ticket in its place.

Urban transport is usually not included in the discount offer. In some cities （e.g. [Lucerne](https://www.luzern.com/en/services/visitor-card-lucerne/)) your hotel may offer you a local travel pass (as a benefit for paying the city tax).

### If you have friends in Switzerland and your timing is lucky

If you happen to arrive in Switzerland during a period where special, you may benefit from discounted day passes even if you do not have a half-fare card.

Right now (August 2022) for example, Coop/Interdiscount is selling [special day passes](https://www.interdiscount.ch/fr/t%C3%A9l%C3%A9phones-mobiles-tablettes-et-wearables/cartes-cadeaux-et-de-codes-de-contenu/cartes-cadeaux-et-de-codes-de-contenu--c100000/carte-journali%C3%A8re-sp%C3%A9ciale-cff--p0001609198) at 49.- each until September 11, with flexible dates between August 15 and October 2. They only deliver to Switzerland, although you could buy them in person as well (but it will take you time to find a store and the stock is not guaranteed).

Swiss Post and Coop/Interdiscount regularly have special day pass offers, but their availability cannot be reliably predicted. Sometimes, the Swiss Federal Railways itself has special sales.

Many municipalities also offer their residents a limited number of day passes each day for around 40.- to 50.-. These day passes are only usable on the day indicated on the pass and are not refundable even if your flight got delayed or the weather is very bad. Most municipalities require the buyer to be a registered resident (subject to certain exceptions). If you have friends in Switzerland (or better you will be travelling with them), this might be an option to consider.

However, special and municipal day passes often do not give discount on certain mountain railways and cable cars (unlike Swiss Travel Pass).

### Discount day passes

If you do not have a half-fare subscription (like most casual tourists), the standard daily option is the one mentioned by the other answer ([discounted day pass](https://www.sbb.ch/en/travelcards-and-tickets/tickets-for-switzerland/day-pass/saver-day-pass.html)).

Like special and municipal day passes, saver day passes also usually do not give right to discount on touristic mountain railways and cable cars.

### Museums

Swiss Travel Pass also includes free entry to most museums. But most Swiss museums are not especially expensive (e.g. Zurich Art Gallery adult rate is 23.-; National Museum 10.-; ), especially if you are young or a student. If you do not intend to visit more than a couple museums and you can get a travel card at a much cheaper price, the museum benefits are relatively peripheral.

If you intend to visit many museums in one city/region, you could also probably find a local museum pass (sometimes included in a local transport pass, e.g. [Zurich Card](https://www.zuerich.com/fr/zurichcard?gclid=CjwKCAjwgaeYBhBAEiwAvMgp2kVzsJipm6Ld24h96KISBDiPmbKceDqT5ksSg9eztLttjZrr_lvPKRoCnFwQAvD_BwE)) for a better deal.

Comment: Thank you @xngtng  for giving comprehensive overview . With saver pass I can take trains/trams to travel within zurich ,lucerne Interlaken and Lauterbrunnen ? Like if I want to catch train from zurich to lucerene and lucerene to interlaken would saver pass be good ? I don't plan to visit museums , just need for travel .

Comment: @arpitjoshi All Swiss-issued travel passes have the same validity area based on the general unlimited travel card: https://www.sbb.ch/content/dam/internet/sbb/en/abos-billette/abonnemente/karte-geltungsbereich-ga-halbtax_en_barrierefrei.pdf.sbbdownload.pdf which does include the trains you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

[Discount daily passes](https://www.sbb.ch/en/travelcards-and-tickets/tickets-for-switzerland/day-pass/saver-day-pass.html) are available directly from SBB/CFF, online or via the mobile app.

The price depends on how early you buy it (up to 60 days in advance). A daily pass bought today (27/08/2022) for tomorrow (28/08/2022) in 2nd class in 119.- Swiss Francs, for Monday it's 106.-, from Wednesday it's 97.-, and so on, and down to **52.- for a day** from 20 September (again, if bought today). First class passes are of course more expensive.

Note however that those passes are only valid for transport, they don't include discounts for museums like the Swiss Travel Pass.

You'll probably need to check the prices for tickets bought individually for your specific travel dates (there can be discounted tickets) and compare with the cost of the various passes. You would need to include both the train tickets and the urban public transport (tram, bus) for a valid comparison of course.

Comment: So with saver pass I can take trains/trams to travel within zurich ,lucerne Interlaken and Lauterbrunnen ? Like if I want to catch train from zurich to lucerene and lucerene to interlaken would saver pass be good ? I don't plan to visit museums , just need for travel

Comment: @arpitjoshi you can find the coverage map here: https://www.sbb.ch/content/dam/internet/sbb/de/abos-billette/abonnemente/karte-geltungsbereich-ga-halbtax-stand_d_barrierefrei.pdf.sbbdownload.pdf it does include trains between Zurich, Lucerne, Interlakenhoheweg and Lauterburnnen and local public transport in the first three. No idea if there’s any local public transport in Lauterbrunnen.

Comment: @arpitjoshi from Lauterbrunnen the trains, buses and cable cars to 
Grütschalp, Mürren, Stechelberg and Wengen are included. Further trains and cable cars in the area (dotted on the map) are not included, but I doubt you would have time for all that anyway.

Comment: Yeah perfect .I just need transport for zurich to lucerne and lucerne to interlaken .And then trams/trains within zurich .

Comment: For just travelling within zurich , interlaken ,lucerne the saver pass should do the magic right ?  I am not going to take cable cars anyhere . Just will be visiting zurich,lucerne,interlaken and if time permits Lauterburnnen . Will be just visiting the city centers  for some touristy stuff as I have approximately less than 48 hours in switzerland .